# Scrollview delegate method also call while scrolling collection view

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I have done this code to get current page while scrolling view and there is a `UICollectionView` on the bottom of the screen.
Problem is, when I am scrolling scroll view it's working fine but this method also working while scrolling `UICollectionView`.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
        let pageNo = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
        print(pageNo)
        if pageNo == 0.0{
            changebackColor()
            dignosticView.backgroundColor = UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: "FC6614", alpha: 1.0)
            dignosticView.layer.borderColor = UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: "f68f56").cgColor         
        }
        else if pageNo == 1.0{
            changebackColor()
            offerView.backgroundColor = UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: "FC6614", alpha: 1.0)
            offerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: "f68f56").cgColor
        }
        else if pageNo == 2.0{
            changebackColor()
            alertView.backgroundColor = UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: "FC6614", alpha: 1.0)
            alertView.layer.borderColor = UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: "f68f56").cgColor
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because collection view is also scrollView. You can put if statement in the first line of scroll view delegate and do nothing if scrollView is from your collection view

```
if(scrollView != collectionView){
   //your code here
}
```